# Trying to click "reject all" pop up box on google.com

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use selenium to visit google and type in something into the search box.  However first I need to accept or reject the cookies.

I think I have coded it correctly to wait for the button to become available, then click it.  However, it keeps throwing a timeout error, suggesting it cannot find that element:

```
search = "physio"
area = "St John's Wood"
url = "https://www.google.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "W0wltc"))).click()
search_box = driver.find_element("name","q")
search_box.send_keys(f"{search} {area}")
search_box.submit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Root cause of your issue:** is that there is no FRAME in the DOM, so there is no need to use `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`.

Change below line:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "W0wltc"))).click()
```

To:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "W0wltc"))).click()
```